# Get SharePoint Column Type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom, scom

I want to create dynamic input according to SharePoint list column type in the web part.

How to get **SharePoint Column Type** in **CSOM** Approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the type of the field using [Field class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.field(v=office.15).aspx).

[image]